# Output an Image in PHP

Tags: php, image

I have an image `$file` ( eg `../image.jpg` )

which has a mime type `$type`

How can I output it to the browser?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there anything wrong in using a `<img>` tag?

Comment: The answers are straightforward and ok.
But don't forget that your script may require the user to be logged on, and if not shows a 404: I was testing my code with another script that used curl to pickup the image; curl wasn't logging in so it got 404s all the way.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

```
$file = '../image.jpg';
$type = 'image/jpeg';
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Comment: PHP and/or the server will take care of the content-length for you.

Comment: The content length header for convenience.

Comment: For some reason filesize failed for me when trying to access the image by absolute path, so I commented that line and the code is working fine.

Comment: It's better to avoid putting Content-Length especially if you have GZip enabled on your webserver, because you'll be telling the browser to expect more bytes than actually arrive, and it will wait to time out. This can have bad consequences if e.g. you have JS waiting for the event.

Comment: Make sure Type in "Content-Type" is capitalized. I just ran into this where it was "Content-type" and it resulted in a bunch of gibberish

Answer (score 33):

If you have the liberty to configure your webserver yourself, tools like [mod_xsendfile](http://tn123.ath.cx/mod_xsendfile/) (for Apache) are considerably better than reading and printing the file in PHP. Your PHP code would look like this:

```
header("Content-type: $type");
header("X-Sendfile: $file"); # make sure $file is the full path, not relative
exit();
```

mod_xsendfile picks up the X-Sendfile header and sends the file to the browser itself. This can make a real difference in performance, especially for big files. Most of the proposed solutions read the whole file into memory and then print it out. That's OK for a 20kbyte image file, but if you have a 200 MByte TIFF file, you're bound to get problems.

Comment: interesting comment about file size and potential memory problems due to reading it all in

Answer (score 29):

```
$file = '../image.jpg';

if (file_exists($file))
{
    $size = getimagesize($file);

    $fp = fopen($file, 'rb');

    if ($size and $fp)
    {
        // Optional never cache
    //  header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    //  header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    //  header('Pragma: no-cache');

        // Optional cache if not changed
    //  header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($file)).' GMT');

        // Optional send not modified
    //  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) and 
    //      filemtime($file) == strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']))
    //  {
    //      header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
    //  }

        header('Content-Type: '.$size['mime']);
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));

        fpassthru($fp);

        exit;
    }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php

Comment: @Michael [via php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/function.getimagesize.php)  

_The getimagesize() function will determine the size of any given image file and return the dimensions along with the file type and a height/width text string to be used inside a normal HTML IMG tag and the correspondent HTTP content type._

Answer (score 5):

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile($image);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  readfile("/path/to/image.jpg");
  exit(0);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

For the next guy or gal hitting this problem, here's what worked for me:

```
ob_start();
header('Content-Type: '.$mimetype);
ob_end_clean();
$fp = fopen($fullyQualifiedFilepath, 'rb');
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
```

You need all of that, and only that. If your mimetype varies, have a look at PHP's mime_content_type($filepath)

Comment: Upvote for the "mime_content_type($filepath)" part. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

*<sup>(Expanding on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1851856/8112776)...)</sup>*

I needed to:

1. **log views** of a `jpg` image *and* an **animated `gif`**, *and,*
2. ensure that the images are **never cached** (so every view is logged), *and,*
3. also **retain** the ***original file extensions***.

---

I accomplished this by creating a **"secondary" `.htaccess` file** in the sub-folder where the images are located.
The file contains only one line:

```py
AddHandler application/x-httpd-lsphp .jpg .jpeg .gif
```

In the same folder, I placed the two 'original' image files (we'll call them `orig.jpg` and `orig.gif`), as well as two variations of the [simplified] script below (saved as `myimage.jpg` and `myimage.gif`)...

```php
<?php 
  error_reporting(0); //hide errors (displaying one would break the image)

  //get user IP and the pseudo-image's URL
  if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {$ip =$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];}else{$ip= '(unknown)';}
  if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];}else{$url='(unknown)';}

  //log the visit
  require_once('connect.php');            //file with db connection info
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if (!$conn->connect_error) {         //if connected then save mySQL record
   $conn->query("INSERT INTO imageclicks (image, ip) VALUES ('$url', '$ip');");
     $conn->close();  //(datetime is auto-added to table with default of 'now')
  } 

  //display the image
  $imgfile='orig.jpg';                             // or 'orig.gif'
  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');              // or 'image/gif'
  header('Content-Length: '.filesize($imgfile));
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
  readfile($imgfile);
?>
```

The images render (or animate) normally and can be called in any of the normal ways for images (like an `<img>` tag), and will save a record of the visiting IP, while invisible to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to send the right Content-type :

```
header('Content-Type: ' . $type);
```

And [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile) to output the content of the image :

```
readfile($file);
```

And maybe *(probably not necessary, but, just in case)* you'll have to send the Content-Length header too :

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

Note : make sure you don't output anything else than your image data *(no white space, for instance)*, or it will no longer be a valid image.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $file = '../image.jpg';
    $type = 'image/jpeg';
    header('Content-Type:'.$type);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    $img = file_get_contents($file);
    echo $img;
```

This is works for me! I have test it on code igniter. if i use readfile, the image won't display. Sometimes only display jpg, sometimes only big file. But after i changed it to "file_get_contents" , I get the flavour, and works!!
this is the screenshoot:
[Screenshot of "secure image" from database](https://image.ibb.co/nht6MF/code.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: $type");
readfile($file);
```

That's the short version. There's a few extra little things you can do to make things nicer, but that'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`finfo`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) (PHP 5.3+) to get the right MIME type.

```
$filePath = 'YOUR_FILE.XYZ';
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$contentType = finfo_file($finfo, $filePath);
finfo_close($finfo);

header('Content-Type: ' . $contentType);
readfile($filePath);
```

*PS*: You don't have to specify `Content-Length`, Apache will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```php
header("Content-type: image/png"); 
echo file_get_contents(".../image.png");
```

The first step is retrieve the image from a particular location and then store it on to a variable for that purpose we use the function file_get_contents() with the destination as the parameter.
Next we set the content type of the output page as image type using the header file.
Finally we print the retrieved file using echo.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you mind updating your answer with some explanation of why your solution works? Could you also remove the quotes from around your answer, as that's making the syntax-highlighter treat it all as a string literal. Thanks!

Comment: Please share some explanation. For example, why did you set `Content-type: image/png` for outputting a JPG image? Also, why read the whole file into a variable? Shouldn't `readfile` have a much better memory performance?