# Count image views

Tags: php, image, view

I would like to have code for an image that counts the number of times the image is viewed, regardless of what site the image is found on. I want to use the img src tag, and have src point to a php page that counts that view and then returns the image to be viewed. I was thinking something like this:

```
 <img src="www.mywebsiteurl.com/something.php" />
```

How would I go about writing "something.php" so that it returns the proper image file? I know how to record the page view, but if I must do something different in this case, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script needs to:

1. Record the hit.
2. Set the content type of the output ( `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` )
3. Output the image ( `readfile( $path_to_image )` );

For examples, please see the [readfile documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/function.readfile.php) and [Output an Image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851849/output-an-image-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

Loading images / files from php is slow than normal loading files.

Main cons:

- Images can't be cached due to dynamic query most browser dont support on dynamic queries.
- Overhead on sever and apache both.

If you use database and want to increment column after image loads than a person can load your image again and again. So you need to use conditions on every query.

**Alternative Solution**

Enter this code in footer of page on which you want to show images

A ajax call

```
$.get("inc_img_view.php?img_id="+<?php echo $img_id; ?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most barebones version you can have:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile('somepic.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call an image using a URL similar to: `www.mywebsiteurl.com/image_renderer.php?url=url_to_image`.

image_rendered.php:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);

$headers = array(  
"GET ".$url." HTTP/1.1",   
"Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8",  
"Accept: text/xml",
"Cache-Control: no-cache",  
"Pragma: no-cache"
);

$ch = curl_init($url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

$r = curl_exec($ch);

// you can connect to your database and increment the number of times this image was viewed

echo $r;
?>
```

Hope this will point you into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're on a good start.
I'd do something like this

```
<img src="www.mywebsiteurl.com/image_counter.php?src=image.jpg" />
```

In image_counter.php, take `$src = $_GET['src']` for image source.

Then +1 the hit for that image in the database.

Then do

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile($src);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['img'];
$path = "images/";

// do an increment of views on the image here - probably in a database?

$exifImageType = exif_imagetype($path.$file);
if ($exifImageType !== false) {
    $type = image_type_to_mime_type($exifImageType);
}

header('Content-Type: $type');
echo file_get_contents($path.$file);
```

Note: this would make something like:

```
<img src="getimage.php?img=image.jpg" />
```

show the correct image after incrementing the views.

You could always add some .htaccess to make all calls to /images/anything go through your image file. It'd mean you could keep the URL looking as though it's getting an actual image file (e.g. /images/logo.jpg would be re-written to actually go through getimage.php?img=logo.jpg)