# How to efficiently count image views(loads)?

Tags: php, apache, file, count

I don't like solutions that require loading images via PHP.

[Count image views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138473/count-image-views)

Nor do I like the ajax solution because say someone leaches or even locally uses the image and forgets the PHP call.

Is it possible to simply parse Apache logs or such to get a more efficient and accurate view count.

If there are such libraries out there already, I would love to know about them, I can't seem to find any. I know there are statistics software like that but it's been near a decade since I've used anything like that (gotten lazy with Google Analytics), would like some recommendation on that as well if it would help.

Comment: @Fabricator thanks, looks interesting, but don't think it's quite what I'm looking for

Comment: Processing the apache log files is the best way to do it. http://www.awstats.org/ or any other package should do the job.

Comment: @mkaatman thanks, this may be what I used nearly a decade ago :P, if you make it an answer and no-one offers anything better, I'll accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a dozen ways to do it.

Apache log processing is probably the best depending on your needs.

I'd check out:
http://www.awstats.org/ or http://www.haveamint.com/