# How to read a file within public_html but outside domain ? using relative path

Tags: php, html, shared-hosting

I'm trying to read a file from a directory outside of my (add-on) domain directory. Here's my directory structure:

```
public_html /
    domain /
        file_read.php
        file_write.php

    sensitive /
        file.dat
```

Although I'm able to write to sensitive using "../sensitive/file.dat", I'm not able to read using the same method. Any ideas why ?

I'm not using absolute path since it'll appear in html source. The domain which public_html belongs to is not being used.

[EDIT] Sharing some code as requested:

file_write.php (sensitive will also have images):

```
mkdir ("../sensitive/dir", 0755);
copy ("resource/in/root/file.jpg", "../sensitive/dir/file.jpg");
move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "../sensitive/dir/newfile.jpg");
```

file_read.php (shows nothing)

```
<img src="../sensitive/dir/newfile.jpg" width="400" height="400">
```

I'm observing the files on sensitive and everything is written OK. I've also manually adjusted permissions of newfile.jpg from 644 to 744 to 755, but no use.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to read and write the file?

Comment: what method? show some code. bet you a dollar its a permission issue

Comment: Added some sample code, thanks. (Also marking @Jim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned `sensitive` is outside the domain directory. Therefore this will not work:

```
<img src="../sensitive/dir/newfile.jpg" width="400" height="400">
```

Which is good! Otherwise anyone could to to `www.example.com/../sensitive/all/your/files.dat`

and have access to the sensitive directory.

If you want to access files in this directory you could write a php page which given some information returns the image (make sure this is secured however or people will be able to access the sensitive directory).

This question provides info on outputting an image: [Output an Image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1851849/505722)