# Image loaded from a PHP script isn't displayed in ImageView

Tags: java, php, android, bitmap, imageview

I want to fill an ImageView with an image saved on my localhost. I can display it in a browser fine but it doesn't get displayed in my ImageView.

PHP script to display image:

```
<?php
include('connect_db.php');

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $path = 'Profile_Images/'.$id.'.jpg';

        echo '<img src='.$path.' border=0>';

?>
```

Here is my android code to download an image from a URL:

```
URL url;
try {
    url = new URL("http://192.168.1.13/get_profile_image.php?id=145");
    new DownloadImage(this).execute(url);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

@Override
public void imageDownloaded(final Bitmap downloadedImage) {

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(downloadedImage);
    }
});
}
```

When I put the URL to some other image it works fine **but mine never gets loaded**, any ideas?

Also, the following code works but I have a feeling its bad practice..

```
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://192.168.1.13/Profile_Images/145.jpg");
        new DownloadImage(this).execute(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Where 145 would be a variable.

**Edit**

Any reasons for the down-votes would be appreciated!

Comment: Apparently, you're using the wrong URL, since the correct URL works. Check whether the first URL works in a browser; if not, then that's your problem.

Comment: The script runs fine in a browser but doesn't fill the ImageView

Comment: Does it "run fine" with both urls? You do see that they are different, right? Also, your php snippet has a reference to `.gif` -- are those `.gif` files?

Comment: Sorry I had that for testing, I have another image called 145.gif which also loads in the browser

Comment: I'm almost certain that `ImageView` doesn't support `.gif`, but it would bear researching.

Comment: I'm almost certain ImageView doesn't support HTML.

Comment: @323go Just after running 11684's PHP script, .gif works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple, actually. When you send a request to `http://192.168.1.13/get_profile_image.php?id=145` a string (`<img src=Profile_Images/'.$id.'.jpg border=0>`) is sent back. Because the DownloadImage class doesn't parse HTML (it wants raw image data) it doesn't know where the actual image is. Two solutions:

1. Your 'bad practice' approach
2. Use this PHP script instead to echo the raw image data:

PHP:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$path = 'Profile_Images/'.$id.'.jpg';

$type = 'image/jpeg';
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
readfile($path);
```

**EDIT:** forgot to credit someone: the above code is taken from here (with adapted variable names): https://stackoverflow.com/a/1851856/1087848

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP code will print out something along the lines of:

```
<img src=Profile_Images/145.jpg border=0>
```

Not only is this malformed HTML, but it is a *text* output. Your other URL, `http://192.168.1.13/Profile_Images/145.jpg` points to an *image* file, from which the data your receive is an image, not an HTML string.

You should consider having your PHP return a JSON response with the URL of the image ID, and then running `DownloadImage` on that URL. The advantage this has over a raw echo is that you can easily expand the solution to return other types of files, and even return an array of files.

Comment: @11684 Hard to believe no one noticed it for 20+ minutes :P You got my upvote

Comment: Yeah, thought so too, after seeing SO spotting the most obscure syntax  ambiguities.