# how can I get image in special url

Tags: php, image, url, curl

I have saw a url like http://www.example.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/0
visit it then I can get a image
how it works?
and how can I get boundary of that image use curl with php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by getting an image by that URL? You need to rewrite the URL with htaccess and intercept it somehow using PHP and loading the file from somewhere.

Once you have the image you can get any info you want to from it.

1. **[Rewrite URL with mod_rewrite](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/)** (i.e.: domain.com/23234234/0 to domain.com?id=23234234&nr=0)
2. **Make a call to the database requesting the file with id 23234234**
3. **[Show it to the user changing the content-type of the file you are showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851849/output-an-image-in-php)**

Is it what are you looking for?