# Display posts without using GET in PHP

Tags: php

How does one make a view contain without using the get variable in PHP

I am trying to display post/id like this

```
www.domain.com/view/1234
```

instead of

```
www.domain.com/view.php?id=1234
```

Comment: It would be logical to display it is as `/view/1234`

Comment: "How does one make a view contain without using the get variable in PHP" does not parse in English. Can you reword this?

Comment: You can specify redirects in the .htaccess file to send all requests to a distributor which checks the requests to route it to the appropriate handler.

Comment: Please clarify your question as to what your use case is here. If you want to link to `/view/1234` that is simple enough. If you have no control over the uri, that is a very different question than if you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewrite the URL with htaccess and intercept it somehow using PHP and loading the file from somewhere.

1. **[Rewrite URL with mod_rewrite](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/)** (i.e.: domain.com/23234234/0 to domain.com?id=23234234&nr=0)
2. **Make a call to the database requesting the post with id 23234234**
3. **Show it to the user**

Is it what are you looking for?

[(based on a previous answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697536/how-can-i-get-image-in-special-url/16697599#16697599)

Comment: You are welcome. If this solved your question, please mark it as solved by clicking on the green Correct icon :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have an Apache server with the `mod_rewrite` module enabled, you can create a new `.htaccess` file with the following content:

```
// First of all we want to set the FollowSymlinks option, 
// and turn the RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

// This is the rule that changes the URL
RewriteRule ^view/([^/.]+)/?$ view.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This would do exactly like you wanted and redirects any `/view/123` to `view.php?id=123`.

Comment: And yet, the OP asked for the reverse. :/

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking for is the ability to parse the uri, you can use this:

```
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
$parts = explode("/",$uri)
```

The last element in your $parts array should be your view id.

Drupal(1) contains the following function to do exactly this:

```
function arg($index) {
  static $arguments, $q;

  if (empty($arguments) || $q != $_GET['q']) {
    $arguments = explode('/', $_GET['q']);
    $q = $_GET['q'];
  }

  if (isset($arguments[$index])) {
    return $arguments[$index];
  }
}
```

(1) I do not advocate using Drupal, I merely use it as an example.

Comment: It really depends on how you want to organize your pages, whether php on page, or url rewriting is the answer.

Comment: The question is pretty unclear. If the OP is trying to simply convert one to the other across an entire site where they don't have control or it would be a major rewrite, I can see that mod_rewrite would be the way to go. If, on the other hand, this is a one-off rewrite is massive overkill and probably more complicated than needed.

Comment: That reminds me of this saying: "I have a problem, so a used a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). Now I have two problems."

Comment: That's a ridiculous simplification. And it's unclear if rewrite is even what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is done via webserver url rewriting.

Here's some references for Apache (using `mod_rewrite`):

- [Apache.Org](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)
- (http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/)