# download and output image in php

Tags: php

Please help me!

I have index.php where is the form

```
<form  id="form" method="post" action="action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 
 <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
  <input type="submit"  value="submit" class="btn btn-success"> 
</form>
```

what should I write in action.php to display the uploaded picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `move_uploaded_file`. Try this..

```
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
} else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
```

Here upload is a folder name in root directory. For more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: How can I display this image ?

Comment: `echo '<img src="upload/'.$_FILES["file"]["name"].'" width="200" height="200">';`. put this line in `else` part.

Answer (score 0):

just upload image file in any folder on your server in root directory by this:

[move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

and save image name in database field column

then you can get that name by from database and can display by this:

```
<?php 
// your mysql query

// goes here
?>

<img src="your_image_folder/<?php echo $your_fetch_row['image_column_name']; ?>" />
```

Comment: direct output image possible?

Comment: yes, you should use javascript for that, but only for uploaded image

Comment: thank you. below is the answer, but I don't know how to display the image. Can I help you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851849/output-an-image-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone. I found the answer!

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){ 

  $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];


  $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $path = "images/".$name;
  move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path);
  echo "<img src='$path' alt='$name' />";
}
```