# Output as an image using PHP

Tags: php, get, mime-types

I'm creating a comments system for my 'CMS' and would like to implement avatars. I would like to have a "getavatar.php" that uses a GET request to find an image for a certain user, while also doing some image processing.

Could anybody point me in the right direction for outputting data as "image/png" from a php script?

An example of this would be http://placehold.it/300x300 in the way it generates a 300x300 png image from the parameters given in the URL.

Comment: Usually you will process the graphics and save as files, either linked to user id, or just a temporary file.  Then you do: `header("Content-Type: image/png"); readfile($filename);` in your script, and the browser will display the image.

Comment: As for image processing, there are many options in PHP, you can use http://php.net/imagecopyresampled for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output an image using PHP: [Output an Image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851849/output-an-image-in-php)

To resize or edit an image using PHP: [resize image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php)

Both answers contains a lot of useful functions. Hope this help you.