# PHP render html code to image

Tags: php, image, render

render.php

```
$form = '<b>Hi</b><br /><img src="test.jpg" /><br />New File';

echo $form;
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagejpeg($form);
```

But this code not work

I want this page render to img file :

```
<img src="render.php" />
```

Comment: Remove last 2 lines, from your render.php. See if that helps.

Comment: `imagejpeg()` *creates a JPEG file from the given image.*

Comment: @GauravDave , not loaded !

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to output both HTML and image-data - that doesnt make any sense.
Instead you should put an HTML-img-tag into your website, the `src`-attribute being `render.php` which sets the header via `header()` and directly outputs image data - **without any additional HTML**.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1851856/351861

Comment: Thx , can you help more ?

Comment: there is nothing more to help you with, you now have a full solution to your problem. If you have more problems you should create another question.

Comment: Thx , But this answer have $file : $file = '../image.jpg'; . my code have not image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You should use extra php file for images, something like:

```
<img src="render.php?id=15" />
```

Because if your php script returns only one picture it is used wrong. so you pass it what image to show.
And render.php might be something like

```
$pic_id = (int)$_GET['id'];// cast to int because only numbers are allowed here
$pic_path = 'assets/img/';
$f = $pic_path.$pic_id.".jpg";// it's just an example so it's simplyfied
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagejpeg($form);
```

The point here is that you can check user's permissions to see the picture very flexible and log some data about downloader.