# PHP: How to restrict the images returned by a php file based on users/groups?

Tags: php, image, restriction

Following an advice on this website I used an `image.php` file to return an image resource, as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29032405/php-how-to-output-image-files) (linking to the images as files is not an option due to security restrictions).

How can I restrict the images that a certain user can 'get' from this `image.php` file?

I am using an OOP MVC architecture in my website. Upon connection, when `index.php` runs, many classes are loaded and instantiated thus the thread has variables indicating who the user is and what resources he can access.

This file `image.php` (returns an image) acts as a 'stand alone' script (accessed by an HTML `src` attribute from the client side), not loaded by the already-running thread, and (forgive me if I misunderstand it) has no variables to indicate who the user is and what he can access.

I could have `image.php` go through the same routine as `index.php`, loading and instantiating classes, but I think it would be a terrible waste of resources for a single image.

How can I restrict the images returned by `image.php` on user basis without creating an additional load on the server?

EDIT: I have observed on some websites that `image.php` is passes a long string GET variable, can that be a method?

If I explained myself in an unclear manner, please be patient and let me know, I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Is there any session data you can use? If so, there's your answer

Comment: Yes, of course. You suggest loading only the resources needed to parse the session and use this data to control access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify the user somehow on image.php and that will depend on how you create the user session. If you are using PHP sessions you could just do:

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
// check permissions
```

Most frameworks use adapters and wrappers to PHP session, on image.php just var_dump($_SESSION) and check if the information you need is there. Don't forget to call session_start.

Comment: Wouldn't it be resource intensive if I have about 20-50 images a page?

Comment: Checking the session is not resource intensive. It's the minimum you need. Passing all images through a PHP script like you are doing is more resource intensive than that.

Comment: Just a follow up, if you are using a database to store session variables you could make is faster by storing the relevant information on memory, thus saving the trip to the database. That could speed things up quite a bit for 50 images. I suggest you to take a look at memcache http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php