# How to get data from database to get url and then place it to Picasso load

Tags: javascript, java, php, android, android-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqb1U.png)

this is my php code..

```
    <?php

if(!isset($_GET['s'])){
    $s = "Berita";
}else{
    $s = $_GET['s'];
}
if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
    header("Location: content_berita_list");
}else{
    $parent = $_GET['id'];
}

   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'manteb_user');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'manteb_pass123');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'manteb_core');
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);


$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM manteb_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' && post_parent = $parent";
$result2 = $db->query($sql2);

if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                $id = $row2['ID'];
                $type = $row2['post_type'];
        $judul = $row2['post_title'];
        $teks = $row2['post_content'];
        $date = $row2['post_date'];
        $gambar = $row2['guid'];
        $parent = $row2['post_parent'];

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
    ?>
      <html><body><?php echo $gambar; ?></body></html>
```

this my class

```
    public class Event implements Serializable {

    public Event(int ID, String post_title, String post_content, String guid, String post_date, String post_parent) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.post_title = post_title;
        this.post_content = post_content;
        this.guid = guid;
        this.post_date = post_date;
        this.post_parent = post_parent;
    }

    public int ID;
    public String post_title, post_content, guid, post_date, post_parent;

}
```

and this is my Picasso

```
public static final String BASE_URL             = "http://manteb.com/";
    public static final String GAMBAR           = BASE_URL + "content_gambar_get.php?id=";


public void onBindViewHolder(EventAdapter.EventViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Event event = eventlist.get(position);

        String fullUrl = PHPLink.GAMBAR + event.ID;

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(fullUrl)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.mantebbw)
                .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
                .into(holder.image_url);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(event.post_title);
        holder.txtDate.setText(event.post_date);

        holder.image_url.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent in = new Intent(context, EventDetail.class);
                in.putExtra("event", event);
                in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivities(new Intent[]{in});

            }
        });
    }
```

and i want to take $gambar to place at Picasso load (url)
i really confuse cz this database is from wordpress default.. tia

Comment: what error occured?

Comment: there is no error..its didnt show the immage.. i just beginer and dont know how to parsing the data from the url that in my php to place at picasso load (url).. so this url at picasso is become data from my url like in my post picture.. or this.. manteb.com/android/content_gambar_get.php?id=2039

Comment: in my code its didnt show the image cz its just url that to show the image url that i want to show.. tia..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't show any picture because you just print the URL. Picasso will try to request `manteb.com/android/content_gambar.get.php?id=2039` but it gets

```
<html> 
    <body>
        http://www.manteb.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/14edonor4_slo.jpg
    </body>
</html>
```

Which Picasso have no idea how to convert that into an image. What you can do is to directly show the image whenever you open the `content_gambar.get.php`. Try using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851849/output-an-image-in-php)

PS: It's better to remove the credentials to your DB when you're using production machine :)

Comment: ty so much dude.. its work fine.. take a couple day to make it work.. cz i'm not good at php.. hehe..