# How can I safely render an Azure-stored image in a browser without revealing the URL?

Tags: php, image, azure

Say I have my file stored at (real credentials removed):

https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/thumbnails/1234567890/thumbnail.jpg

A) This file is currently downloadable if I simply browse to it - I really don't think that should be possible.

B) I want to render this in my app without allowing the user to see the URL.

I am using PHP on the backend. Is there some method wherein I download the image to the server and render it from there? Is that efficient?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: To `A)` thats how it works. You can download everthing you can see. To `B)` but then the user can just rihgt-click an save image as or just do a screenshot of the page?!  Everthing that is parsed to the browser (client) is not anymore under your control.

Comment: I don't mind that they save the image at all. I just don't want to reveal the storage structure of our images.

Comment: Ok, then parse the image directly with php read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1851856/4916265  download the file with `file_get_contents('http://')` to local place and output it with method in the link. The real called file from the userbrowser can something like `getImage.php?id=refertotherealurl`

Comment: write a script and put it on your `src=` attribute instead of the images url eg `src="getimg.php?id=1234567890"` then serve the real image from that script

Comment: base64 encode the image and use something like `src="data:image/jpeg;base64,....`

Answer (score 1):

These are the options you have:

1. Make the blobs/container public and embed with the public URL
2. Generate a temporary SAS token for the blob and embed with URL + SAS token
3. Download the blob from your backend with a storage key and stream it through it to the client

With option 1 the file must be publicly accessible, which I guess you don't want.

That leaves options 2 and 3.

If you are okay with revealing the URL, but only giving the user temporary access to the file, option 2 can be a good one.

Otherwise you only have option 3.

The good side of options 1 and 2 is that the blob download happens from Storage to user directly, and your app doesn't have to spend time/bandwidth on streaming files.

Comment: I would go for option 2, just generate a short-lived sas token. The URL will be visible, but it will expire soon. Disadvantage of option 3 is that, at scale, it will impact the way you have to scale your webapp because you don't offload the traffic to the storage account. This might lead to an expensive situation :)