# How to use a media file located outside of public folder on a website? (PHP, HTML)

Tags: php, html, image, directory-structure

I'm curious about this, and I think I'm half way to a "no", but I'm not an expert.

Having a directory structure like the following, and being `public` the public root of a website:

[image: directories and files: www dir. Inside it public and not public dirs. Inside public, index.php. Inside not-public, img.jpg and abc.php.]
.

Every `.php` file shown can be used to generate the webpage.

But, in the generated HTML, `img.jpg` can't be found.
Not with relative nor absolute paths, as far as I tested.

**Is there a way to display this image on this website without moving it into `public` directory? (Permission changes and witchcraft allowed.)**

**If not, then why?**

Comment: You might be able to use a symbolic link. But also why are you doing this?

Comment: Curiosity only. You mean creating links to non-public files in the public directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public media (images, javascript etc.) should be accessible from public directory, but there are solutions to work around this.

You can display PHP code as an image.

[Output an Image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851849/output-an-image-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On the question you linked, they use ```header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');```, I understand that will show the image only. While that answer this question; are you aware of a way that would allow to use the image as a part of a bigger content? (as an example: text, img, more text)

Comment: It works the same. URL to image called with PHP may be ended with `.php` or even `.jpg` when you join it with proper `mod_rewrite` settings.

Comment: You can create kind of proxy for your images.